# Graph not showing up on Jupyter lab

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

The below set of code previously worked well and I was able to visualise the boxplot graph well. This code was previously used in another project of mine, and it worked perfectly well. There were no changes done to this piece of code, and it is being reused here.

I have a 'df' dataframe and I am trying to create boxplots to visualise outliers. Unfortunately, the graph doesn't seem to visualise anything. I am not sure what is wrong with my set of code. Could someone please help?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'TotalPrice':[1.000, 0.650, 0.0075, 0.0025, 0.200], 
                   'Voltage':[13.47, 13.41, 13.41, 13.41, 13.41], 
                   'ConversionFactor':[934.0, 934.0, 2580.0, 934.0, 934.0],
                    'Litres':[40.0, 26.0, 3.0, 1.0, 8.0]})

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

%matplotlib inline
%pylab inline

df = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,4, figsize = (8, 4))

ax[0].boxplot(df.TotalPrice)
ax[1].boxplot(df.Voltage)
ax[2].boxplot(df.ConversionFactor)
ax[3].boxplot(df.Litres);
```

[image]

The dataframe sample:
[image]

Comment: what does your dataframe look like?

Comment: Dataframe sample attached.

Comment: DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: _The below set of code previously worked well_ - define 'previously'

Comment: When you say _previously used in another project_ -- did this previous project use the same environment, i.e. Jupyter Notebook? This is the crucial bit of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change from `inline` to `notebook`, and remove your *pylab* reference, it will work as expected within Jupyter Notebook:

```
%matplotlib notebook  #< not inline
# %pylab inline       #< this is not needed
```

Comment: Perfect answer !

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to import `df`. Your code returns the following error:

```
Populating the interactive namespace from numpy and matplotlib
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-d9ef2c853adf> in <module>()
     12 fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,4, figsize = (8, 4))
     13 
---> 14 ax[0].boxplot(df.TotalPrice)
     15 ax[1].boxplot(df.Voltage)
     16 ax[2].boxplot(df.ConversionFactor)

NameError: name 'df' is not defined
```

Comment: I have already imported the dataframe, my code is now edited.

Comment: add `plt.show()`? I don't know I have no access to your dataframe.